# What is the maximum number of line continuations in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, syntax

I have been looking all around Bing and Google trying to find this, does anyone have an answer? How many line continuations will the compiler tolerate in VB.NET 2010 (.NET 4)?

Comment: If you are writing something that long, please refactor...

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on doing that now, ... though it's not easy, because this guy designed a DISASTER of a data-model. He did this back in VB6 days, and ... on top of that, he wasn't actually a programmer either... someone's brother or cousin or something they had build them a system. We inherited the maintenance on it, and any time we have to do any significant changes to it, it is always a nightmare. But I am getting some weird errors now, and was wondering if I hit some limit or something. Sounds like not though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is .NET 4 I would say is pretty limitless, specially since automatic line continuations have been introduced on this version for things like LINQ queries, Attributes, etc. and those can get out of hand pretty quickly so I would say the limit should be either too high or not exist at all.

The issue becomes: How readable does the code gets once you have chained a big number of line continuations?

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard limit in the compiler.  It will simply keep processing them until it runs out of memory and crashes.